# filtering names by multiple conditions ( age range and gender) in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter

this is in my text and code so far:

```
{
      "people": [
        {"name": "Jack", "gender": "M", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Jerald", "gender": "M", "age": 24},
        {"name": "Jim", "gender": "M", "age": 23},
        {"name": "Bill", "gender": "M, "age": 22},
        {"name": "Barry", "gender": "M", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Rikki", "gender": "M", "age": 35},
        {"name": "Ross", "gender": "M", "age": 33},
        {"name": "Jane", "gender": "F", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Bela", "gender": "F", "age": 24},
        {"name": "Cheeky", "gender": "F", "age": 22}
      ]
    }

import pprint
import json

my_data = json.loads(open("people.json.txt").read())


print "Choose the lowest age limit:",
age_from = int(raw_input())
print "Choose the highest age limit:",
age_to = int(raw_input())

print "People age from %r to %r." % ( age_from, age_to)

def filter_by_age_range(members, age_from, age_to):
print'%s'  % name [1]
```

I was trying to follow a certain webpage about filtering but I cant seem to put in use the filter method especially when two conditions are to be met. Example is if I need males (M) and ages 22 to 25. I am trying also to figure out if only one condition is to met that is what I have so far in my code but the programs runs without error but it doesn't give my desired output.I also have no idea what the name[1] does. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me solve this problem as well as help me understand the filter function. Btw is it correct that i used int() for my prompting? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could use list comprehension and apply on each row a filter function

```
def filter_by_age( person, age_from, age_to ):
    if age_from <= person['age'] <= age_to and person['gender']=='M': return True
    else: False

filtered_people = [ p for p in my_data['people'] if filter_by_age(p, age_from, age_to) ]
```

Comment: thanks it worked so if i need to put the people whose names corresponds to it what should i put? for example  I need males (M) and ages 22 to 25. I need to print  only the names of the person for which it is true not the whole line?

Comment: in the list comprehensions you could apply any function on each matching element (the elements are here dictinaries). e.g., if you are only interested in the names you could do: `[ p['name'] for p in my_data['people'] if filter_by_age(p, age_from, age_to) ]`. list comprehension is a really useful tool. check out the section List Comprehension here [https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html]. there are also dict comprehensions and set comprehensions.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the help.. hope you can answer my other questions next time as I am new to programming :)

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda person: person['age'] >= 22 and
    person['age'] <= 25 and person['gender'] == 'M', members['people'])
```

or

```
[person for person in members['people'] if person['age'] >= 22 and
    person['age'] <= 25 and person['gender'] == 'M']
```

both do the same thing.

Comment: the first one has an error, says members are not defined. the second one gives an invalid  syntax

Comment: You call it `my_data`, I call it `members` (as you did in your function). Not a big deal. (I forgot to drill into `people` in one of them; fixed now. Shouldn't be a syntax error, I just tested both.)